# Incorporate offline bible in phonegap app?

Tags: javascript, html, json, cordova

Can you give some idea on how to incorporate an offline bible in a phone gap based app? It may require bookmarks of chapters and verses in the future. How will I go about doing this. A local json file may be? But I couldn't find a json that makes sense. Looking for the KJV Bible. Also not sure how to make the json approach scalable to comply with bookmarking. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

The full text is only [~4MB](http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/10), which means that it should not be a problem to load the full text into memory when your app runs.  And then, JSON should be fine for bookmarking -- because of how the Bible is structured, it is a simple matter to have nested hash/array lookups:

```
var bible = {
    genesis: [
        [  // first chapter
            "In the beginning God created the heaven and the earth.",
            "And the earth was without form, and void; and darkness was upon the face of the deep. And the Spirit of God moved upon the face of the waters.",
            ...
        ],
        [  // second chapter
            "Thus the heavens and the earth were finished, and all the host of them.",
            "And on the seventh day God ended his work which he had made; and he rested on the seventh day from all his work which he had made.",
            ...
        ],
        ...
    ],
    exodus: [
        [  // first chapter
            "Now these are the names of the children of Israel, which came into Egypt; every man and his household came with Jacob.",
            ...
        ],
        ...
    ],
    ...
};
```

Any verse should be very quick to look up using this structure: to pull the book, it's a hash-map lookup, and then chapter and verse are array offsets.